# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined in three.js line 468

Tags: three.js

This is my first time attempting to import an obj into three.js and use it. I am attempting to use the object loader that is included in the three master build.

The issue seems to be in how the object file loads, as it errors about something being undefined in some kind of loop. Trouble is, I don't know what is undefined that shouldn't be.  To create my obj file I used https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/media/uploads/demos/w/i/wizgrav/f232e401f674086f9aae99b474e27ed0/running-image-triang_1372626220_demo_package/index.html

What am I doing wrong? This is my first time using Three, so I tried to make as few changes as possible (only to where the files are in my directory structure).

Since this could be the object, it is at:
  http://geevideoproduction.com/geeTop3D.obj

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
        <title>three.js webgl - loaders - OBJ loader</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: Monospace;
                background-color: #000;
                color: #fff;
                margin: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            #info {
                color: #fff;
                position: absolute;
                top: 10px;
                width: 100%;
                text-align: center;
                z-index: 100;
                display:block;
            }
            #info a, .button { color: #f00; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script src="./jscript/three.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./jscript/js/loaders/OBJLoader.js"></script>

        <script src="./jscript/js/Detector.js"></script>
        <script src="./jscript/js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>

        <script>

            var container, stats;

            var camera, scene, renderer;

            var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

            var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;


            init();
            animate();


            function init() {

                container = document.createElement( 'div' );
                document.body.appendChild( container );

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000 );
                camera.position.z = 100;

                // scene

                scene = new THREE.Scene();

                var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x101030 );
                scene.add( ambient );

                var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffeedd );
                directionalLight.position.set( 0, 0, 1 );
                scene.add( directionalLight );

                // texture

                var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
                manager.onProgress = function ( item, loaded, total ) {

                    console.log( item, loaded, total );

                };

                var texture = new THREE.Texture();

                var loader = new THREE.ImageLoader( manager );
                loader.load( '/PlayFiles/geeVideoProduction/images/GeeTop.png', function ( image ) {

                    texture.image = image;
                    texture.needsUpdate = true;

                } );

                // model

                var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );
                loader.load( '/PlayFiles/geeVideoProduction/images/geeTop3D.obj', function ( object ) {

                    object.traverse( function ( child ) {

                        if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {

                            child.material.map = texture;

                        }

                    } );

                    object.position.y = - 80;
                    scene.add( object );

                } );

                //

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );

                //

                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

            }

            function onWindowResize() {

                windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
                windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            }

            function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

                mouseX = ( event.clientX - windowHalfX ) / 2;
                mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfY ) / 2;

            }

            //

            function animate() {

                requestAnimationFrame( animate );
                render();

            }

            function render() {

                camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * .05;
                camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * .05;

                camera.lookAt( scene.position );

                renderer.render( scene, camera );

            }

        </script><div><canvas width="1244" height="500"></canvas></div>



</body></html>
```

Comment: Any luck on getting this to work?

Comment: I getting the same error message but only for some STL files. Do you have any insights on that issue?